# How to change the Column Names of a database created by Django (from models.py)?

Tags: mysql, django, database, phpmyadmin

So I have a MySQL Database in my local PHPMyAdmin with DBs and Tables already filled in with data. I have to now port that DB into django.

For example, the name of a table in the DB is "ratings". So using django, I have to first create an app named something (let's say "website") and then I can add the model ratings to that app. This creates a table "website_ratings" in the DB. Which is not what I want, I want the name of the table to be just ratings.

Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the table name and column names in the model class. Here is an example:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(db_column='column_name')
    # other fields

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ratings'
```

It means for every field you can specify a column name, which can be different than the field name. In the `Meta` class you can specify the table name. Otherwise Django creates it automatically out of the app label and the model class name.

If it is a legacy database and you want to create model classes, you can use the following command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Usually you'll have to edit the file after that according to your needs.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton :)