# Django rest framework api with existing mysql database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, legacy-database

How can I create a Django REST Framework API that connects to an already existing MySQL tables instead of creating them through `modela.py`. My `models.py` shows something like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

Instead of this, I need to take data directly from existing tables in MySQL.

Comment: Check this doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: Whatever database you have you cab revert create a model, that won't affected to your database. `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` yes the same @neverwalkaloner has suggested.

Comment: now i got it. thank you guys

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Why don't you provide a short answer with a simple example?

Comment: @cezar I dont think I can describe it as good as official docs:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the Column Names of a database created by Django (from models.py)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676100/how-to-change-the-column-names-of-a-database-created-by-django-from-models-py)

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to define same class name as your table name with meta char field

like for example
`RandomTable(id INT(10),name varchar(10))` is your existing mysql table then the `models.py` for it will be

```
class AppnameRandomTable(models.Model)
    id = models.CharField(db_column="id") #name of column of existing db
```

## inside that you will need to write the fields of your existing table name in meta section

```
class Meta:
    db_table = "RandomTable" #your existing mysql table name
```

### time saving hack just create a class in models.py and on terminal run "python manage.py inspectdb" you will automatically get all the column names from there.

You can just copy and paste names from there , because for reading and writing on columns you need to define their variables in your class even if the table is existing mysql table

Answer (score 2):

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

If you run that command it will create a models.py in the project's root directory. Once you've done that you can either move it directly into the project or create a models folder and break it down into areas of concern from there. You will likely have to do the work of adding `related_name = 'foo'` to a lot of fields that have relationships with other models. That can be time-consuming but it works.